# AOSP for a chinese (allwinner arm cpu) build

Tags: android, android-source

Friends, I am new in AOSP. Have done the tutorial here:
[AOSP tutorial by google](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements)
Have built my own 7.1.2 custom build with the modifications I needed. It works perfectly fine on the emulator! Happy days!

Next step would be to reproduce the same thing on the real device and this is where all my confusion comes from.

I probably incorreclty but do believe that if I build aosp_arm-eng with the lunch option will produce a 32bit build for an arm architecture processor. Aosp_arm64-eng will do the same but for a 64bit variant.

I get the *.img files at the end of the build and just started to look it up how to flash *.img files (with fastboot?) to the real device when I found an article saying that the lunch setups is populated from the envsetup.sh file which is irrelevant for my device. For my device I need to have a "custom build". 
Excuse me?

This makes me think that for every individual make of android devices you need to have a different 'build' (?) to create your own build? This doesn't make any sense to me.

If someone undestands my confusion can please make the things clear?

Can I use the aosp_arm-eng build *.img files to flash a 32bit arm device? If not, why not?

MILLION thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: I read a lot and I think I start getting it. aosp_arm-eng will build android for a 32bit arm processor, but with very generic hardware/driver modules. So the processor could run android but the chipset around will not match to the build and this is why it wont work. Is this correct?

Comment: If the above is correct, this also means that you need to rebuild your android for every single device where the hardware is not 100% the same even though that the android version number is the same. This all means that two android 7.1.2 for example could not be the same. If this all is true, this is ridiclious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same android release (branch [android-7.1.2_r28](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds) for example) the build of two different devices (Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P for example) will result in two different builds.

The build result of the Nexus 5X will not be compatible with Nexus 6P and reciprocally.

Android is not like Ubuntu or Windows, where one image is compatible with a lot of devices.

To add your own device to AOSP, consider reading: [Adding a new device](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device)

Comment: Thanks, accepted. Can you please clarify what do the "proprietary blobs" mean? Did a lot searching on this but this is still not clear. Some says these are hardware specific files to use the chipset, bluetooth, wifi chip..etc. Some says that these are just the files in the system/ directory (but doesnt explain what are they doing.) The question is, if I have a device that is not supported by google and would like to compile my own AOSP OS, do I really need these files or is it enough to fill in the make files like it is mentioned in your link? Many thanks

Comment: Proprietary blobs are often related to hardware driver or proprietary (non open source) material. Take a look at this [page](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers). You will see all the driver binaries for Nexus or Pixel Devices and their purpose.